# Request to let [reference] reference [reference-request]

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently, there is a [reference](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference) tag with 9 questions tagged so. However, not only the tag has no tag wiki/excerpt but also is being used similarly to the [reference-request](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) tag. Therefore, let the tags [reference](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference) and [reference-request](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) be merged.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist if the feature to merge synonymous tags is present why not use it? Also, even if '"reference is just the initial substring of "reference-request"', people still made the tag and we can not stop people from making it again in the future.

Comment: Any tag can be blocked, which means nobody can recreate it: [What is a blocked tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295148/what-is-a-blocked-tag) This can happen to tags when the community agrees they are undesirable.

Comment: @mdewey: Note that in general, we'll only block a tag if it has been previously burninated (i.e. removed from all questions) but then ends up getting created again. If it's never been burninated before, a tag block generally isn't necessary yet.